# Hide/Show specific divs

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have 2 divs. One menu and one content div

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu One</a></li>
        <li><a>menu Two</a></li>
        <li><a>menu Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Content one</div>
    <div>Content two</div>
    <div>Content three</div>
</div>
```

On first page load, the CONTENT ONE is on the page.
Now, when I click "menu Two", I want to show the CONTENT TWO. When I click on CONTENT TWO all other content close, only the CONTENT TWO is on page and so on...

How can I accomplish this using arrays in jQuery? Any other method is fine too.

Comment: Can you check all the answers?

Comment: I'd edit my answer. Can you look at it?

Comment: Hi ebilgin, I edit my question :) Do you can help me, one more time?

Comment: What do you mean arrays? I understand a little of your question, please explain more.

Comment: Your test was great but my html structur is a little bit different. You can see my html structure here: https://jsfiddle.net/janwill/n44gtyLd/1/. Now I need a solutions for every first LI: "<li>Content one",  "<li>Content two",  "<li>Content three". On page load you have to see the LI " "<li>Content one", by click on MENU TWO the whole LI  "<li>Content one" have to hide and the use can see the LI ""<li>Content two"...and so on. In your fiddle example everything is OK, but the script hidden the nested li too...

Comment: I´m planning to build an archive like this: http://www.vie-nomade.com/archives/. By click on the year, you can see whole dates from the year and the first year (2015) is hidden....

Comment: I'd edit my answer, please check it out.

Comment: AWESOME!!! Thx for your help... Everything is fine, now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a fiddle for your question. https://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/n44gtyLd/3/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu One</a></li>
        <li><a>menu Two</a></li>
        <li><a>menu Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>Content one
            <ul>
                <li>Content one one
                    <ul>
                        <li>Content one one one</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Content two
            <ul>
                <li>Content two two
                    <ul>
                        <li>Content two two two</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li>Content three
            <ul>
                <li>Content three three
                    <ul>
                        <li>Content three three three</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content > ul > li:nth-child(n+2) {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var menuItems = $("div:eq(0)").find("li");
var contents = $("div:eq(1)").children("ul").children("li");

menuItems.on('click', function () {

    var index = menuItems.index( $(this) );
    showContent( index, true );

});

contents.on('click', function () {

    var index = contents.index( $(this) );
    showContent( index, true );

});

function showContent( index, allHide ) {

    if ( allHide )
        contents.hide()

    contents.eq( index ).show();

}
```

Comment: Thx for your FIDDLE. This is great but is it possible to hidden the other contents if I click on a menu item? At the beginning, it`s right that I see CONTENT ONE but if I click - for example - menu Two -> CONTENT ONE should hidden and only CONTENT TWO is to see... Puh, my english isn`t so good :(

Comment: Thats awesome!!! THX... but, please help me one more time, please. I have create a new html structure. Here is the new one. Please take a look....https://jsfiddle.net/janwill/n44gtyLd/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li').click(function(){
  $('div > div:eq('+$(this).index()+')').show();
});

//when user clicks on any content is hides all except the current content
$('div > div').click(function(){
$('div > div').hide();
$(this).show();
});
```

Comment: ` `When I click on CONTENT TWO all other content close, only the CONTENT TWO is on page and so on.``

Comment: Nop. look at answer provided by me and pranav. that is how it should work.

Comment: Do you can help me and show me a demo on fiddle, please :) I don`t understand jquery so good. But when I see the code in action, it`s ok...